# Codeigniter select custom using active records

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, select, activerecord

I can't imagine how to select custom content from DB with active records. My code:

```
$select = array('mixed' => 'WHERE id = 2 OR id = 5');
$query = $this->db->select('*');
$query = $this->db->query($select['mixed']);
$query = $this->db->order_by('id DESC');
$query = $this->db->get($table);
```

query returns me:

> 0.0001     WHERE id = 2 OR id = 5
>
> 0.0002     SELECT * FROM po_posts_content ORDER BY id DESC

so how to make it right?

**UPDATE:**

changed `$this->db->query($select['mixed']);` to `$this->db->where($select['mixed']);`
and all worked FINE

Comment: What is the point? Why do you need to use the custom query and the query builder at the same time?

Comment: @HashemQolami becouse I call function from model with custom params. And sometimes I need to select custom data. Now I need not with AND but with OR

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
$this->db->where_in('id', array(2,5));
```

or

```
$this->db->where('id =2 or id =5');
```